# ReactJS + Redux + Reduc-thunk Can't dispatch promise

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx, redux-thunk

I have this message when i try to dispatch a promise with redux and i d'ont see what i wrong

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

1) Here my createStore

```jsx
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import RootReducer from '../reducers/root.reducer'

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  const store = createStore(
      RootReducer,
      preloadedState,
      compose(
          applyMiddleware(thunk), createLogger()
      )
  )
  return store
}
```

2) In my component i dispatch my action like this

```jsx
dispatch(myAction(myParam))
```

3) Here is myAction code

```jsx
export function myAction(dispatch, myParam){
    return fetchList(myParam)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err)
          throw err
      })
}
```

But if i call my action like this, it's work :

```jsx
myAction(dispatch, myParam)
```

I think there is redux-thunk problem but why ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `redux-thunk` you have to return a function from you action creator.
`dispatch` would be passed to this function as a first parameter so you can call it anywhere inside the function to `dispatch` different actions.

```js
export function myAction(myParam) {
  return dispatch => {
    fetchList(myParam)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS,
          list: json
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err)
          throw err;
      });
  };
}
```

Read the [docs](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Thunk allows an action creator to return a function instead of plain-object, so you use it like

```js
export function myAction(myParam) {
  return dispatch => {
    console.log("IN ACTION");
    fetchList(myParam)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS,
        list: json
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err)
      throw err;
    });
  };
}
```

You were returning a Promise object, that was the part of the problem.